# How to find left and right cosets of a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Q:" G group, H subgroup. G=D6, D diedras group, and H=. Find the cosets of H."

I don't understand the method to find the cosets, I've searched for answers but somehow it stays confusing... 
Being aH the left coset, do I give an arbitrary value from $D_6$ to $a$? And how does it multiply by $H=\{e, r, r^2, r^3, r^4, r^5\}$?

Answer (score 1):

There's no "method" to compute cosets, just the definition.

Given $a\in G$, the coset $aH$ is the subset of $G$ consisting of the elements of the form $ah$ as $h$ varies through $H$.

In the case under question $G=D_6$ and $H$ is the subgroup of rotations, so

- if $a\in H$ the coset $aH$ is just $H$;
- if $a\notin H$ the coset $aH$ consists of the 6 elements in $G$ not in $H$.

(These two claims should be checked)

A general property of cosets is that they define a *partition* of $G$. This can be easily verified in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

When we write $aH$, it means that we multiply *each element* of $H$ by $a$ on the left.  That is:
$$aH = \{ae, ar, ar^2, ar^3, ar^4, ar^5\}$$

To find *all* the cosets of $H$, you need to do the above computation for every possible value of $a\in G$.  (Note that two different values of $a$ may give the same coset.)